# Difference between multimap and unordered map

Tags: c++, data-structures, dictionary, hashmap, multimap

I was reading about c++ `multimap` and it states that `multimap` allows inserting duplicate Keys.This makes me think that a `multimap` uses a `hashmap` for underneath implementation (since a hashmap allows duplicates incase of collision) then I also read that `unordered map` uses a `hash map`. My question is then whats the difference between the two. I tried looking for comparison between the two but I could not find anything that would explain this.

Comment: Don't conflate contract with implementation. Plus, "since a hashmap allows duplicates incase of collision" is downright wrong: the collision on the _hashes_, not the actual keys.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, collision resolution (the fact that it happens) *is* part of the contract of hash tables. Specifically, it's the clause that permits the hash function to return the same value for keys that are not equal.

Comment: @delnan: I was referring to the OP's reasoning about contracts based on supposed implementations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A hash table permits and resolves collisions of *hash values*. It only stores one copy of each key value (as determined by `operator==` or another equality relation). But if two *distinct* keys hash to the same value (bound to happen), *that* is handled by collision resolution. For each key, there is a single value.

A multimap is an ADT that associates *multiple* values with each key instead of one. It's not a particular implementation strategy: It can internally use a hash table, a search tree, or something completely different.